# Software to sync an iPod that auto converts audio and video to correct format?

Tags: software-recommendation, ipod

Does any software exists that actually convert audio to be fonctionnal on my iPod (ex : .ogg to .mp3) and convert videos to a format working on an iPod?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arista Transcoder is what you need.

[One Click Install](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/arista)

Comment: Arista is NOT what you need. It doesn't work. I have never had it produce a video that wasn't badly out of sync with the audio, and that didn't have horrible problems with video stuttering. It's worse than useless.

Answer (score 0):

Avidemux is a decent choice for video.  Although Arista looks like might fit your bill for both jobs.  I haven't tried either yet personally.  I typically end up using ffmpeg or the like.

Answer (score 0):

For video nothing beats Handbrake. Amazing piece of software. Link to forum [discussion](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=705640).

Answer (score 0):

Last time I checked, Banshee transcodes files when transferring them; completely automatic: comes with a very nice interface for iPods/Android devices, too.

Comment: With my IPod (generation 6, 80GB), most of the time Banshee does transcode correctly, video and audio is not useable afterwards on my IPod.

Comment: not useable? iPod Nano; 3rd Gen. Works perfectly. Hmm...